# vb.net FolderBrowserDialog warning

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I searched for a proper way to use the `folderbrowserdialog` but i'm getting a warning and I don't get why.

I added the folderbrowserdialog on my form in the design window.

Then I used this code, like I found on various websites.

```
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        tb_CopyToPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
```

And visual studio is giving me following warning.

> BC42025
>
> Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type
>   through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

What do I need to change to remove this warning?

Comment: Yes, this is a `windowsform` and I have a textbox called `tb_CopyToPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning is because you're inside a `Form` (which has a `DialogResult` property) and you're using `DialogResult` enumeration (of which `OK` is a `Shared` member). Compiler is telling you that you're accessing a `Shared` member (`OK`, in this case) through an instance (`DialogResult` property value, which *by case* is also of type `DialogResult`).

AFAIK it has been solved long time ago but if you're using an *old* VB.NET compiler then you may still need to specify full type name (which will disambiguate between property and type name):

```
FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
```

---

<sub>Side comment about naming convention: pick a proper name for `FolderBrowserDialog1` and do not use underscore in identifiers...</sub>

Comment: My target framework is `.NET Framework 4` its not the newest but old? I don't know. I'm using a template for Autodesk Inventor and it was initially set like this. I tried raising the to `.NET Framework 4.5` but same result.

Comment: Why do you suggest not using underscore in identifiers?

Comment: If you can target .NET 4.5 then it's a _new_ VB.NET compiler. Weird but if you use full namespace you can get rid of that warning (anyway it's long time I don't program in VB.NET so I may be wrong about when/if they solved this). About underscore: it's not inherently wrong but contrary to usual .NET naming conventions (where case is used to separate words).